# Browser sending unallowed requests

Tags: google-chrome, browser, virus, malware, anti-virus

I've got some malware so now my browser is sending requests to strange sites:

[image]

Also if I click on any html element in a browser It may redirect me to unwanted pages

I've tried to fix this using malwarebytes and adwcleaner and other basic cleaning methods like reinstalling the browser, cleaning the Task planner in windows, deleting some extensions in browser etc.

So the question is how do I fix my browser from this ads with free software or any other methods?

Comment: Reinstall browser & use https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/krd18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is an option, but the best idea is to do a clean reinstall of the operating system. I had tried in the previous years to remove malware with different software but, more or less, they returned.

The best way that I found is to do a clean reinstall of the operating system, install a reliable anti-virus and be more careful about the sites you're visiting.